# How to derive the equation from trigonometric funtions

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms, trigonometric-series

How to derive the equation from Line #1 to Line #2? I have tried different trigonometric functions but could not get it. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Use identities

$$\cos \frac{\theta_n }{2} =\cos \left(\theta_n -\frac{\theta_n }{2}\right)=\cos\theta_n \cos\frac{\theta_n }{2} +\sin\theta_n \sin\frac{\theta_n }{2}$$

and

$$\sin \frac{\theta_n }{2} =\sin \left(\theta_n -\frac{\theta_n }{2}\right)=\sin\theta_n \cos\frac{\theta_n }{2} -\cos\theta_n \sin\frac{\theta_n }{2}$$

Comment: Thanks @MotylaNogaTomkaMazura. I have tried to expand the equation but could not get what is shown in Line #2. Can you please show the steps?